# node express hits :id instead of 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, express

I'm developing a small API collection to study `nodejs` with `express` and I've found myself in this situation. I have `app.use("/v1/phrases", phraseRouter);`

In the router I have the following code:

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const jwtHandler = require("../../auth/jwt-module");
const controller = require("./phrases.controller");


router.get("/hash", jwtHandler.authenticateJwt, async (req, resp) => {
    try {
        const hash = await controller.getCollectionHash();
        resp.status(200).send(hash);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error on /phrases/hash =>", error);
        resp.status(500).send(error);
    }
});

router.get("/", jwtHandler.authenticateJwt, async (req, resp) => {
    try {
        const phrases = await controller.listPhrases();
        resp.status(200).send(phrases);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error on /phrases =>", error);
        resp.status(500).send(error);
    }
});


router.get("/:id", jwtHandler.authenticateJwt, async (req, resp) => {
    const phraseId = req.params.id;
    try {
        const phrase = await controller.getPhrase(phraseId);
        resp.status(200).send(phrase);
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.code) {
            console.log("error on /phrases/:id =>", error);
            resp.status(error.code).send(error.msg);
        } else {
            resp.status(500).send(error);
        }
    }
});

router.post("/", jwtHandler.authenticateJwt, async (req, resp) => {
    try {
        const phrase = await controller.addNewPhrase(req.body);
        resp.status(201).send(phrase);
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.code) {
            console.log("error on post to /phrases =>", error);
            resp.status(error.code).send(error.msg);
        } else {
            resp.status(500).send(error);
        }
    }
});

router.put("/:id", jwtHandler.authenticateJwt, async (req, resp) => {
    const phraseId = req.params.id;
    try {
        await controller.updatePhrase(phraseId, req.body);
        resp.sendStatus(204);
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.code) {
            console.log("error on put to /phrases/:id =>", error);
            resp.status(error.code).send(error.msg);
        } else {
            resp.status(500).send(error);
        }
    }    
});

router.delete("/:id", jwtHandler.authenticateJwt, async (req, resp) => {
    const phraseId = req.params.id;
    try {
        await controller.deletePhrase(phraseId);
        resp.sendStatus(204);
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.code) {
            console.log("error on delete at /phrases/:id =>", error);
            resp.status(error.code).send(error.msg);
        } else {
            resp.status(500).send(error);
        }
    }
});

router.get("*", (req, resp, next) => {
    console.log("hit this");
});

module.exports = router;
```

For some reason which eludes me, whenever I type a route that doesn't exist, like `/v1/phrases/imnotreal` I end up hitting the `:id` instead of my 404 block. I'm searching all the web for an answer but I still haven't found a clear solution. Can anyone help me?

Comment: i would put a path component to root it - the id is acting like a wildcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a `:param` as a part of your path, it matches everything like `/*`.You can get the params value from the request using `req.params.param`. In your case `/imnotreal` matches with the `/:id`, so it ends up hitting the route with `:id` as the param. What you can   do is use **regular Expressions to capture the path patterns**. So if your id would consist only of digits then instead of using

`router.get("/:id"`

you can use

```
router.get(/^\/([0-9]+)$/i)
```

This would match the paths with digits. For eg:
`/123456`
and not
`/imnotreal`